# Accidentally oped 2008 SSIS solution file in new version of Visual Studio. Cannot open any 2008 SSIS package anymore

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2008

I accidentally oped 2008 SSIS solution file in a new 2012 version of Visual Studio. Cannot open the any 2008 SSIS package anymore. I've tried creating a new solution but is still gives the error shown below. 
Please advise. [image: SSIS 2008]

The point is that I do not need to open it in 2012 at all. 2008 packages are not compatible with 2012. I'm opening it through 2008 Integration services. But getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the issue is to open Integration Services 2008 solution file previously opened in later version Visual Studio version is open it with Visual Studio Version Selector

[image: Visual Studio Version Selector]

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error, it doesn't seem to be related to your solutions compatibility levels, but rather your installation of visual studio itself. Make sure it is fully updated (and in particular has this update: https://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=36020), and if that fails I'd try uninstall/reinstall visual studio/SQL server data tools.

Comment: The point is that I do not need to open it in 2012 at all. 2008 package are not compatible with 2012. I'm opening it through 2008 Integration services.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you - if you don't need to open it in 2012, why are you looking for a solution to a problem with your installation of 2012? Do you mean that opening your solution files from the OS now launches 2012 instead of 2008? If so, look at : https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-change-file-associations-in-windows-2624477 to learn how to change the association back to 2008.

Comment: Exactly write. opening your solution files from the OS now launches 2012 instead of 2008. I'll read. Thanks

Comment: But wait a minute. I'm opening a file directly from Integration Services 2008. So that File Associations in Windows should not matter, shouldn't it?

Comment: I believe when you use integration services to edit a package it simply exports it as a file and tells the OS to open it, so OS file association would matter.